# Filter SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, filter

I am using multidb pattern in Zend Framework.

Typically I will be using master/slave architecture of MysqlDB.

So my question is what should I do to execute SELECT queries from slave database and INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries on master database

My application.ini looks like

```
resources.multidb.primary.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.multidb.primary.host = localhost
resources.multidb.primary.username = root
resources.multidb.primary.password = 123456
resources.multidb.primary.dbname = tubaah_zend
resources.multidb.primary.default = true

resources.multidb.secondary.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.multidb.secondary.host = localhost
resources.multidb.secondary.username = root
resources.multidb.secondary.password = 123456
resources.multidb.secondary.dbname = tubaah
```

So I want to run all SELECT queries on secondary database and all INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on primary database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe insert/update/delete should work just fine, i.e.:

My_Model_DbTable_MyTable.php:

```
function myFunction() {
    $this->insert()
    $this->update()
    $this->delete()
}
```

However, if you wish to use the secondary database, you may be unable to use the typical $this->select() method:

My_Model_DbTable_MyTable.php

```
// Override getAdapter() function to be able to obtain secondary database
function getAdapter($name = 'primary') {
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    $resource->init();

    // Ensure only primary and secondary are allowed
    if ($name == 'secondary' || $name == 'primary') {
        return $resource->getDb($name);
    } else {
        return $this->_db;
    }
}

function selectFromSecondary() {
    $db = $this->getAdapter('secondary');
    $select = $this->select(true);
    return $db->fetchAll($select); // normally this is $this->fetchAll()
}
```

Again, by overriding getAdapter() as shown above, you won't need to make any changes whatsoever if accessing the primary database, but if you need the secondary one you need to obtain the secondary adapter via $this->getAdapter('secondary') and store it into a variable, i.e. $db, and then call select/insert/update/delete methods using the $db object.

***EDIT*** Slight modification to code above. You should try to utilize $this->_db by default for getAdapter() and the $db-> replaces $this-> for fetch(), update(), insert(), delete(), etc, not for select().

Answer (score 1):

```
function getAdapter($name = 'primary') {
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    $resource->init();

    // Ensure only primary and secondary are allowed
    if ($name == 'secondary' || $name == 'primary') {
        return $resource->getDb($name);
    } else {
        return $this->_db;
    }
}

function selectFromSecondary() {
    $db = $this->getAdapter('secondary');
    $select = $this->select(true);
    return $db->fetchAll($select); // normally this is $this->fetchAll()
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for your answers guys but stil I am not clear. I simply want a centralized function that is executed before any MySql query is executed and that function will change connection on run time depending on the type of query i.e. if query is select then execute on db-2 and if query is insert,update or delete then execute it on db-1. Hopefully I am clear